# Unity JSON Serializer not allowing for calling JSON Fields n JSON Objects

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, jsonserializer

The have an issue where I am unable to call nested JSON Objects from a scraped website. The scraping process works prefectly, but the JSON Serializing part is the only issue. My code is shown below:

```
private void GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyDetail));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html.Result));
        stream.Position = 0;
        MyDetail dataContractDetail = (MyDetail) jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
        text.text = "" + dataContractDetail.results[1];
        //text.text = string.Concat("Test: ", dataContractDetail.question, " " + dataContractDetail.correct_answer);
    }

    public class MyDetail
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<string, questions> results
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public class questions
        {
            public string question { get; set; }
            public string correct_answer { get; set; }

        }

        [DataMember]
        public string response_code
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

This code is the code that does not work, in that I try to call the first object in results by doing "results[1]", which returns an error after I attach, say, "question" to it by doing "results[1].question". This syntax seems reasonable, so I don;t understand why it is not working. My JSON File is shown below:

```
{
"response_code": 0,
"results": [
{
"category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "medium",
"question": "What is the name of the virus in &quot;Metal Gear Solid 1&quot;?",
"correct_answer": "FOXDIE",
"incorrect_answers": [
"FOXENGINE",
"FOXALIVE",
"FOXKILL"
]
},
{
"category": "Geography",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "easy",
"question": "What is the official language of Costa Rica?",
"correct_answer": "Spanish",
"incorrect_answers": [
"English",
"Portuguese",
"Creole"
]
},
{
"category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "medium",
"question": "In Fallout 4, which type of power armor is first encountered in the early mission &quot;When Freedom Calls&quot; in a crashed Vertibird?",
"correct_answer": "T-45",
"incorrect_answers": [
"T-51",
"T-60",
"X-01"
]
},
{
"category": "Politics",
"type": "boolean",
"difficulty": "medium",
"question": "George W. Bush lost the popular vote in the 2004 United States presidential election.",
"correct_answer": "False",
"incorrect_answers": [
"True"
]
},
{
"category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "medium",
"question": "In &quot;Halo 2&quot;, what is the name of the monitor of Installation 05?",
"correct_answer": "2401 Penitent Tangent",
"incorrect_answers": [
"343 Guilty Spark",
"031 Exuberant Witness",
"252 Biodis Expolsion"
]
},
{
"category": "Entertainment: Books",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "medium",
"question": "The book &quot;Fahrenheit 451&quot; was written by whom?",
"correct_answer": "Ray Bradbury",
"incorrect_answers": [
"R. L. Stine",
"Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart",
"Stephen King"
]
},
{
"category": "Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "hard",
"question": "In &quot;Rick and Morty&quot;, from which dimension do Rick and Morty originate from?",
"correct_answer": "C-137",
"incorrect_answers": [
"J1977",
"C-136",
"C500-a"
]
},
{
"category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "hard",
"question": "In which game did the character &quot;Mario&quot; make his first appearance?",
"correct_answer": "Donkey Kong",
"incorrect_answers": [
"Super Mario Bros.",
"Super Mario Land",
"Mario Bros."
]
},
{
"category": "Entertainment: Film",
"type": "multiple",
"difficulty": "hard",
"question": "What was Humphrey Bogart&#039;s middle name?",
"correct_answer": "DeForest",
"incorrect_answers": [
"DeWinter",
"Steven",
"Bryce"
]
},
{
"category": "Entertainment: Cartoon & Animations",
"type": "boolean",
"difficulty": "medium",
"question": "In &quot;Avatar: The Last Airbender&quot; and &quot;The Legend of Korra&quot;, Lavabending is a specialized bending technique of Firebending.",
"correct_answer": "False",
"incorrect_answers": [
"True"
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: "in that I try to call the first object in results by doing "results[1]"" Just for reference, C# arrays are zero-index based, so the first result would be 0 not 1. (Not that it relates to your issue, I reckon.)

Comment: The results json has 10 objects, so results[8] and results[0] should return a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues in your code. I don't know all the libraries you are using but here is how I would do it.

First of all you start a `GetStringAsync` but you continue immediately without waiting for results. I don't know all the libraries you are using ofcourse maybe it is supposed to be like that?

However I would rather use Unity's [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html)

```
private void GetHtmlAsync()
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadJson());
}


private IEnumerator DownloadJson()
{
    var url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10";
    using(var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        // send the request and wait for result
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        // Check for success!
        if(uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uwr.error))
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Download failed with {uwr.responseCode} reason: {uwr.error}", this);
            yield break;
        }

        var json = uwr.DownloadHandler.text;

        // ... se below
    }
}
```

Again I don't know your JSON library but your class seems not to match the JSON data structure which would be (by simply jamming it through [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com))

```
[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public string category;
    public string type;
    public string difficulty;
    public string question;
    public string correct_answer;
    public List<string> incorrect_answers;
}

[Serializable]
public class MyDetail
{
    public int response_code;
    public List<Result> results;
}
```

for Unity I would use `[Serializable]` and also remove all the `{get;set}` in order to not use properties but fields.

Then you could simply use Unity's [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

```
...
MyDetail dataContractDetail = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyDetail>(json);
```

Then as mentioned in the comments note that array indices in c# are `0`-based so the **first** element would be

```
var firstResult = dataContractDetail.results[0];
```

Now the question is what do you want to see on your text? The `firstResult` is no `string` but rather a class having various members! You could e.g. want to display the question like

```
text.text = firstResult.question;
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer! You saved me a lot of time, truly. I appreciate your help!!